# Java pattern matching using regex

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I am new to java coding and using pattern matching.I am reading this string from file. So, this will give compilation error. I have a string as follows :

```
String str = "find(\"128.210.16.48\",\"Hello Everyone\")" ; // no compile error
```

I want to extract "128.210.16.48" value and "Hello Everyone" from above string. This values are not constant.

can you please give me some suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Not a valid string literal.

Comment: Describe your possible values so we can understand the pattern.  For example, do you expect invalid IP addresses and if you do, what should be their fate?

Comment: This string , I am reading from file. So,                         String str = "find(\"128.210.16.48\",\"Hello Everyone\")" ;

Comment: I see no research effort in this question. I downvoted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

```
String str = "find(\"128.210.16.48\",\"Hello Everyone\")" ;
System.out.println(str.split(",")[0].split("\"")[1]);
System.out.println(str.split(",")[1].split("\"")[1]);
```

Output:

```
128.210.16.48
Hello Everyone
```

**Edit:**
Explanation:

For the first string split it by comma `(,)`. From that array choose the first string as `str.split(",")[0]` split the string again with doublequote `(")` as `split("\"")[1]` and choose the second element from the array. Same the second string is also done.

Comment: can you please give me the explanation ? So that I can understand the working of split.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use `String#split()` method but still if you are looking for regex pattern then try it and get the matched group from index 1.

```
("[^"][\d\.]+"|"[^)]*+)
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/eV5aP3/4)

Sample code:

```
String str = "find(\"128.210.16.48\",\"Hello Everyone\")";
String regex = "(\"[^\"][\\d\\.]+\"|\"[^)]*+)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

output:

```
"128.210.16.48"
"Hello Everyone"
```

Pattern explanation:

```
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    "                        '"'
    [^"]                     any character except: '"'
    [\d\.]+                  any character of: digits (0-9), '\.' (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
    "                        '"'
   |                        OR
    "                        '"'
    [^)]*                    any character except: ')' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
  )                        end of \1
```

Comment: also this tool might help but its not 100% accurate http://txt2re.com/index.php3?s=find(\%22128.210.16.48\%22,\%22Hello%20Everyone\%22)&-11&-52&-70&-48&4&3&-54&-72&-73&-51&-50

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is fine, but if for some reason you wanted to still use regex (or whoever finds this question) instead of String.split here's something:

```
String str = "find(\"128.210.16.48\",\"Hello Everyone\")" ; // no compile error
String regex1 = "\".+?\"";
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(regex1);
Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(str);
while (matcher1.find()){
    System.out.println("Matcher 1 found (trimmed): " + matcher1.group().replace("\"",""));
}
```

Output:

```
Matcher 1 found (trimmed): 128.210.16.48
Matcher 1 found (trimmed): Hello Everyone
```

**Note:** this will only work if `"` is only used as a separator character. See [Braj's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3218114/braj) demo as an example from the comments [here](http://regex101.com/r/eV5aP3/5).

Comment: This will not work if string contains `"` as well. [demo](http://regex101.com/r/eV5aP3/5)

Comment: True, I will edit that caveat into my answer. Thanks!